# GWT and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gwt

We have RoR application and we are planning to make js interface(extjs or closure) in new version.
Is it possible to use GWT with RoR?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this is still the accepted answer, decided to update with more modern approaches

### RESTful API

The tooling for creating and consuming API's has improved markedly.

- *Creating* REST JSON API from RoR is simple. [Basically set controller to respond to a JSON request and serialise model to JSON](https://blog.codelation.com/rails-restful-api-just-add-water/)
- *Consuming* REST API from GWT has a good Stack Overflow answer [how-to-call-restful-services-from-gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030969/how-to-call-restful-services-from-gwt)

### RoR to GWT RPC project (very dated)

The http://code.google.com/p/gwt-rails/ project is intended to provide easy to use RPC between RoR backend, and GWT UI.

Comment: gwt-rails is not updated around 5 years as of 2015 May, hope someone click "Export to github" button on the google code to continue development.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, using GWT with RoR is perfectly possible. Client server communication will be by JSON, which RoR can easily produce. GWT works best when you're creating a client side app in HTML/JavaScript/CSS, if you want progressive enhancement of an existing HTML UI jQuery etc. might be a better choice.

Comment: Although gwt-query (http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) has been getting a lot of updates recently, so that might be worth checking out too.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you won't have the nice RPC mechanism available with java based servers. You'll probably have to use RequestBuilder class to pass data to the server & back.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not that familiar with GWT but I guess in theory it's possible to use GWT cross compile Java into JavaScript which is then used within a Rails application. It sounds pretty cumbersome though.