# Web Service for Gwt Application

Tags: web-services, gwt, tomcat

What type of web service is supported by gwt application i have tried using Jersey, RESTful, Restlet, but nothing works with GWT. I want to deploy Web-Service on Tomcat and GWT application on app engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx all for your suport . . i have got the answer for my question. 
i created a restfull web service using Jersey and called it using the following code in my gwt app engine application:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.first").build());
String obj=service.path("rest").path("bye").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
```

and the web application code is :
    package de.vogella.jersey.first;

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;

@Path("/bye")
public class Hello {

// This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String sayPlainTextHello() {
  return "Hello it worked";
}
```

For Web Application Code refer to this link:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use RPC and RequestBuilder:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication

You can also use RESTful services:

[How to call RESTFUL services from GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030969/how-to-call-restful-services-from-gwt)

Comment: i am using restlet web service and calling it using request builder, but it returns response code 0.

Comment: this ibm example is going up of my head.